# laying out your javascript

Tags: javascript, layout

Right here's my question how are the cool kids laying out their javascript these days? I've been looking around and from what I can tell everyone seems to be doing it different some people contain their functions inside object literals, some seem to just list there functions and have all there variable listed above. So what does eveyone think how should I be laying out my code.

```
var logsomestuff ="somestuff";

function logIt(){ 
   console.log(logsomestuff);
}
```

or maybe

```
logIt = {
   logsomestuff: "somestuff",
   logIt: function(){
      console.log(this.logsomestuff);  
   }
}
```

I don't know what do people think, best way to layout your js? above are just two example I'm sure there are a ton more. Thanks for anyhelp

Comment: This type of question is better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Interesting topic, but i think the question is way to general for this forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the cool kids are using function closures to scope their variables.

This code executes immediately and leaves nothing in the global scope, everything is hanging off the jQuery $.app variable.

```
(function($) {

  $.app = $.app || {};

  $.app = { 
      log : function(stuff) {
        console.log(stuff);
      },
      helpers : { 
          convertJsonDateString = function(date) {
               return "somecrazyregex";
          }
      };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Closure is by far the "cool" kids way of doing things these days, for the reasons Dave mentioned and also because it actually allows Javascript to have some structure. The way I set my modules up is typically like this:

```
var ModuleName = function(sandbox, options) {

    //Class functions
    function someButtonHandlerOrSomething() {

    }

    return {
        init: function() { //Initialization logic }
        load: function() { //Load }
        destroy: function() //On exit }
    }
}
```

I also use a core function to abstract libraries such as jQuery so my application is not dependent which admittedly forces me to write a lot of vanilla Javascript, but I actually prefer it that way.

This video helped me a lot: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw